Nginx Conf file gives 404
I am trying to always append https, www and ending slash to any url; I have the following code in my nginx conf file
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name testsite.co.uk;

        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ https://www.$http_host$1/ permanent;
        
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.testsite.co.uk;

        #return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ https://$http_host$1/ permanent;       
}

If the URL is http://www.testsite.co.uk/yes I am expecting https//www.testsite.co.uk/yes/ (working as intended with above code. However if I try to go http://www.testsite.co.uk I get a 404 instead of redirecting to https://www.testsite.co.uk/ If I comment out the rewrite line and use the return 301 the home page works. Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks

[^/] after the * looks wrong to me. In my head it shouldn't work on any of your examples since it should only match start of line or /.
